# Why can't I write to a file in python

Tags: python, file, python-itertools, palindrome

I have a python program that generates palindromes and writes them to a file. But then I wanted to modify the code to generate only palindromes that were meaningful (i.e in the dictionary). So I looked up a .txt version of an English dictionary that I could use in my python program on the internet. So the problem is, before I added the code that read the dictionary file, the palindrome program was working perfectly and writing the palindromes to the file I specified, but when I added that `if` statement (that checks whether the palindrome generated is in the dictionary) to the program, it stopped writing to the file. Here is the code:

```
import itertools, math
from string import ascii_uppercase

def vowel(string):
    return any(v in string for v in 'AEIOU')
         
MAX_LEN = 8
FILENAME = "Palindrome_Dict.txt"
NUMBERS = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE', 'SIX', 'SEVEN', 'EIGHT', 'NINE', 'TEN', 'ELEVEN', 'TWELVE', 'THIRTEEN', 'FOURTEEN', 'FIFTEEN', 'SIXTEEN', 'SEVENTEEN', 'EIGHTEEN', 'NINETEEN', 'TWENTY']
DICT = []

f = open("english3.txt", 'r')
DICT = f.readlines()
DICT = list(map(lambda w: w[:-2], DICT))
f.close()
    
with open(FILENAME, 'w+') as file:
    file.writelines(["ALL THE POSSIBLE PALINDROMES\n", "By: Ayinde-Oladeinde Ayoife (a.k.a Index)\n"])
    
    for n in range(3, MAX_LEN):
         list = []
         
         sentence = f" {NUMBERS[n-1]} LETTER PALINDROMES "
         file.writelines(['\n'+sentence+'\n', '-'*len(sentence)+'\n'])
         
         l = math.ceil(n/2)
         for w in itertools.product(*[ascii_uppercase]*l):
            word = ''.join(w)
            
            if word[0] not in list:
                file.writelines(['\n'+f"--{word[0]}--\n"])
                list.append(word[0])
            
            word = word + word[::-1] if n % 2 == 0 else word + word[:-1][::-1]
            '''if word.lower() in DICT:
                print(word)

file.writelines([word.capitalize()+'\n'])'''
            file.writelines([word.capitalize()+'\n'])
```

As you can see from the above code that i commented the if statement that checked whether the word was in the dictionary list. And this code works as expected but once you uncomment that if statement and you check the Palindrome_Dict.txt file you'll see that the file is completely empty.
I've tried everything i could and i really need your help in fixing this bug. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you sure `word` is in `DICT`? pay attention to whitespaces and case.

Comment: Why are you trimming the last two characters from every string read from the file?

Comment: If you are trying to remove DOS line endings, they should automatically be translated to single linefeeds by the stream itself. `open("english3.txt").readlines()` should be returning something like `['foo\n', 'bar\n']`, not `['foo\r\n', 'bar\r\n']`. (You can get the latter by opening a DOS text file using `open("english3.txt", newline='\n')`, but I can't think of a good reason to do that.)

Comment: In general, if you are surprised that `word.lower() in DICT` returns false, verify that `DICT` contains the strings you think it should first.

Comment: @Guy Yeah I'm very sure that ```word``` is in ```DICT```. I put a ```print``` statement after that ```if word.lower() in DICT``` statement to check if the generated ```word``` is in ```DICT```

Comment: @chepner i trimmed the last two characters because there is a newline character ```\n``` at the end of each item in ```file.readlines()```

Comment: `\n` is a *single* character in the string that is represented by a digraph. Using the `rstrip` method to remove a *possible* newline is better than unconditionally striping a character via slicing anyway. `DICT = list(map(lambda w: w.rstrip('\n'), DICT))`, for example. (Or `DICT = [w.rstrip('\n') for w in DICT]`.)
`

Comment: `"foo\n"[:-2] == "fo"`

Comment: @chepner Thanks, have modified it but it's not still working

Comment: And I noticed something, anytime I mention ```DICT``` in that ``` with``` block, it's not going to write to the file but if I remove the ```DICT``` statement, it's going to work. But I really need that DICT 

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would like to thank everyone that helped me with the question. And I want to say that I've found a temporary fix to the problem and I found the solution on this website https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/860/ which mentioned that `file.flush()` immediately writes the preceding `.write()` or `.writelines()` statement to the specified file, which is what I did. And like that, the problem was solved.